# Is there a way to get a complete name bibliography from Scopus? How can I set my scrape, in that case?

Tags: citations, scopus

I need a complete name bibliography from a search but I'm only allowed to have the surname and then the names'initals. Is there a way to get them?

Comment: By "scrape" do you mean "filter"? Also, I'm not convinced that this question is on-topic, since it's basically asking for questions on how to use a very specific software tool to accomplish a very specific task.

Comment: @aeismail but it is a specific search in specific software that many others may like to make.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to click on the author and it will take you to the author details page. There you will find the complete name of the author.

The bibliography you are exporting should be in the form as it is. While you can follow the above description for complete names.

Comment: The way you are mentioning works for one paper only. I think he is seeking for an automatic procedure by which he can change his report from a `Family name, N.` to `Name, Family Name` format in the author's column.